# Using $in to return all documents that match list

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDb. I'm trying to execute a query to search a collection and return all documents that match a list of names (strings).

Here is my query:

```
{
db.employees.find({ "n": { "$in": ["Alice", "Mary"]}})
}
```

But I'm getting the error:

"Field names in dot notation need to be in quotes at line 2, col 22"

Which is the character before "n". What gives? Thanks!

Comment: What are you wrapping the method with `{}`? That is what is giving the error. It's just `db.employees.find({ "n": { "$in": ["Alice", "Mary"]}})` and **NOT** `{ db.employees.find({ "n": { "$in": ["Alice", "Mary"]}}) }` which is incorrect.

Comment: This is using Studio 3T for Mongo, and it says that is necessary. When I remove those it says "Unexpected character 'd' at line 1, col 1", so I know that is not the error

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out *doh*. When using studio 3t, the collection is implicitly implied. As such, you only need to type:

```
{ "n": { "$in": ["Alice", "Mary"]}}
```

not

```
db.employees.find({ "n": { "$in": ["Alice", "Mary"]}})
```

Silly error, leaving this up in case someone finds it useful